# Docker not allowing to run stop, kill or pause commands with or without sudo

Tags: server, permissions, 22.04, docker, lts

I'm trying to restart a container from docker but whenever I try to stop it, kill it or pause it always tell me that permission is denied.

However I've tried using the mentioned commands with sudo and I still get the same result.
I have also tried to add a sudo user to the docker group but that didn't help with the problem at all.

The errors I get look something like this:

`Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: nginxproxymanager: permission denied`

And the command I am issuing is:

`sudo docker stop nginxproxymanager`

Any and all help is appreciated!